# how do i turn an input into a variable so i can add or use in equations in python

Tags: python

if I have a code like this?

```
num1= input (" number goes here")
num2= input ("number goes here")
```

how can I make a simple equation work such as.

```
num3=num2+num1
print ("num3")
```

and when I do that it outputs

```
num2num3
```

I have tried things such as

```
int=(num1)
```

Comment: `int=(num1)` should be `num1 = int(num1)`, and then also add `num2 = int(num2)`

Answer (score 5):

You need to convert num1 and num2 into int type because input gives you a str type.

```
num1 = int(input(" number goes here"))
num2 = int(input("number goes here"))
num3 = num1 + num2
print(num3)
```

Comment: thanks i knew it was simple i was just stuck